# Converting a data frame into a list in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, dataframe

I have a dataframe "a" which looks like this

```
a1  a2  a3
a   1   45
b   2   55
c   4   34
d   3   87
```

and I need to convert this dataframe into a list, which looks like this

```
a   a2  1
a   a2  2
a   a2  4
a   a2  3
b   a3  45
b   a3  55
b   a3  34
b   a3  87
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Comment: Your output makes little sense to me - why is column one `a` and `b` only? `stack(a[-1])` maybe?

Comment: a and b is just an example

Comment: @Doej The output you showed doesn't look like a `list`

Comment: then how does it looks like? I thought its in the form of a list

Comment: @Doej It looks like a `data.frame` without the column names.  A `list` looks likes `as.list(1:3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a new column with elements 'a', 'b' using `Map` by looping over the 2nd and 3rd columns, `rbind` the `list` elements with `rbindlist` and use the `idcol` option to create the 'grp' column from the `names` of the `list`.

```
 library(data.table)
 setnames(rbindlist(Map(data.frame, df1[-1], 
       letters[1:2]), idcol='grp'), 2:3, c('v1', 'v2'))[]
#   grp v1 v2
#1:  a2  1  a
#2:  a2  2  a
#3:  a2  4  a
#4:  a2  3  a
#5:  a3 45  b
#6:  a3 55  b
#7:  a3 34  b
#8:  a3 87  b
```

#### data

```
df1 <- read.table(text="a1  a2  a3
 a   1   45
 b   2   55
 c   4   34
 d   3   87", sep="", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Error: could not find function "setDT"

Comment: @Doej You have to load `library(data.table)`

Comment: what is df1 and 2:3 in the command?  @akrun

Comment: @Doej It is your initial dataset

Comment: @Doej THat is right and if you look at my post, I used it as `data.frame`.

Comment: I want it to be extended for N number of columns, Now how I do the same thing for a dataframe of 5X5 matrix?

Comment: @Doej You can use the same code except that use `letters[1:5]` and in the `setnames` change accordingly

Comment: If I am replacing the values of the column a1 with other characters, still in the output list it is showing the values a,b,c..

Comment: @Doej It is because if you look at the initial dataset you used, the output doesn't seem to come from the 1st column.  Are you saying the number of elements in the first column is based on the number of columns selected?

Comment: No, I just that when I replace the values of column a1(a, b,c) to a1(as, bs,cs) in the output column V2 still prints a,b,c values

Comment: @Doej It is because you are using `letters[1:3]`.  instead use `df1$a1[1:3]` i.e. `setnames(rbindlist(Map(data.frame, df1[-1], df1[1:3,1]), idcol="grp"), 2:4, paste0("v", 1:3))[]`